# Programming java in Eclipse Kepler. I need a quick short cut to my java source code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

Is there a way to shorten my number of clicks to get to my source code? I know that search can do this but is there a way to create short cut?

Comment: try to search the shortcut in Eclipse help....

Comment: Google "Eclipse Keyboard Shortcuts"

Comment: From where? F3 is nice in source, Ctrl-alt-t is nice most places.

Comment: Your code is full of shortcuts. Use `ctrl + left click` on a class or a method. If you want to quickly find a class, use `ctrl+shift+t`. If you need a resource (jsp, css, js, xml), use `ctrl+shift+r`

Answer (score 1):

When you are in the 'Java' Perspective, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, then type the name of a Java class. Eclipse will find it and open it. You can also specify wildcards e.g. `*` and `?`

You can also type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to search content contained within a variety of workspaces resources.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+R has the added benefit of searching all resources, not just Java classes, so it will also show XML, property files, your POMs (if you're using Maven), etc. Though keep in mind that you'll have to use Ctrl+Shift+T to search for classes outside of your projects.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> is the shortcut for searching a resource in eclipse